# Help making Lipschitz proof rigorous

Tags: calculus

A function $f:R→R$ is defined to be Lipschitz if there is a constant $K>0$ such that for all $a,b∈R$ $$|f(a)−f(b)|≤K|a−b|$$

Suppose $f:R→R$ is Lipschitz. Prove that $f$ is continuous.

Could someone please verify that my solution is completely rigorous? I think that there may be a slight problem with my proof since I used $|x-y|<δ$ and not $0<|x-y|<δ$. If this means that the proof is not rigorous, I would very much appreciate it if someone could fix the proof so that it is rigorous. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If $f:X\to Y$ is Lipschitz, with Lipschitz constant $K$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous, since if $\epsilon>0$ is given, then for $\delta = \frac{\epsilon }{K}$ it holds that for all $x,y\in X$ with $d(x,y)<\delta $, $$d(f(x),f(y))\le K\cdot d(x,y)=K\cdot \frac{\epsilon}{K}=\epsilon.$$

Since any uniformly continuous function is continuous (this follows immediately from the respective definitions), the claim is proved.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'm not quite sure I understand what the difference between your solution and my solution is. Do you mind explaining the differences? Also, this is the first time I have been exposed to the notion of Lipschitz functions, so if your solution involves knowledge of properties of a Lipschitz function, unfortunately I will not understand it. Thanks again.

Comment: @JoeS the difference is conceptual more than anything. There are different 'degrees' in which a function between metric spaces can be continuous. Lipschitz is a pretty strong one, which implies uniform continuity. That was the point of my solution.

Answer (score 0):

let $ϵ>0$ and $x,y ∈R$

for $f$ to be continuous at $y$, need to ensure that $|f(x)−f(y)|<ϵ$

we are given $$|f(a)−f(b)|≤K|a−b|$$

now, whenever $|x-y|<δ$ we have: $$|f(x)−f(y)|<Kδ$$

let $δ = \frac{ϵ}{K}$

therefore we have: $$|f(x)−f(y)|<ϵ$$

therefore by choosing  $δ = \frac{ϵ}{K}$  we have ensured that whenever $|x-y|<δ$, we have $$|f(x)−f(y)|<ϵ$$

i.e. $f$ is continuous on all $y∈R$

i.e. $f$ is continuous over its domain.